TQuery.open generates pending requests
When executing the TQuery.Open command and monitoring my application using dbMonitor, I see that it generates 4 lines:

I don't think the pending lines have an impact on my application's performance, however I don't know why this is happening. Also, when I re-run the query, I get only one line with the status "complete".
Do you have any ideas on why this is happening?
